# How to correctly handle errors in Perl

Tags: perl, file-io, error-handling

I am trying to keep my command prompt from closing when there is an error in opening a file.  I already tried the 'die' command, but that closes the command prompt right after the message is displayed.  I want to be able to print an error message, wait a few seconds, then close or exit.  Right now, I can get the code to wait before closing the prompt, but it never displays my error message:

```
open (LOG1, $file1) || (print "\n# Error in opening $file1, make sure it exists! #\n", sleep(3), exit);
```

Comment: This is only an issue if you're running your perl script as the main process in a window. Using Windows? If so, you might want Win32::Die

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misusing the comma operator - print doesn't print the error message, but the return value of `exit()`! Use semicolons instead.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are developing using a Windows system. If so, you can try adding the following code in your script which will display: 'Press any key to continue ...' just before the script exits.

```
END { system 'pause' }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `sleep` does no flush the output buffer, so that could explain why you don't see anything printed out; you could try:

```
open (LOG1, $file1) || ((print "\n# Error in opening $file1, make sure it exists! #\n"), $|++, sleep(3), exit);
```

In any case, it seems to me that it would be much preferable to define a `dieAfterDelay` function like this:

```
sub dieAfterDelay {
    my $msg = shift;
    my $delay = shift;
    my $errNo = shift;
    print $msg . "\n", $|++;
    sleep($delay);
    exit($errNo);
}
```

that you could use like this:

```
open (LOG1, $file1) || dieAfterDelay("\n# Error in opening $file1, make sure it exists! #\n", 3, -1);
```

Comment: $| 

If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or print on the currently selected output channel.

Comment: What does it do in this example, specifically?

Comment: What it does is flushing the output buffer right after the `print` statement. That was just a try...